# Why did the recent Elana41 mission fail?

Tags: propulsion, failure, astra-space

On February 10, 2022, the Astra LV0008 rocket failed mid-flight, shortly after stage separation. It appeared to ignite and then shut off repeatedly, while also spinning out of control. Do we know what caused the failure? Why?

Comment: I don't think there's any official information available yet, so I don't think anyone can really answer this question. This video from Scott Manley raises a few good points though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLfl6ADRyu0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Astra's press release on the matter](https://astra.com/news/post-launch-investigation-what-we-found-and-next-steps/) as well as multiple comments made during the official Spaceflight Astra-1 LV0009 livestream

there were two separate issues that, combined, caused the incident.

First, there was an error in an engineering drawing which caused some cables for the payload fairing deployment mechanism to be connected the wrong way. This caused the fairing deployment mechanism to fire in the wrong order, which in turn resulted in off-nominal movement of the fairing. This off-nominal movement, in turn, led to an electrical disconnection which prevented the last deployment mechanism to fire.

This was not caught by ground testing because all the individual unit tests as well as hardware-in-the-loop tests were based on that same engineering drawing. In other words: the tests were verifying that the cabling matched the drawing, not that the drawing itself was correct.

This was the issue which caused the payload fairings to not deploy fully and thus the second stage to fire while still partially enclosed in the payload fairing.

Secondly, there was a software error which prevented the second stage avionics package to command the thrust vector control system. The second stage was not able to control its attitude and thus spun out of control.

The root cause of this was packet loss. While the software is generally resistant to packet loss, there was an unexpected set of circumstances that had not been foreseen.

Both the engineering drawing and the software have been fixed.

---

**[EDIT]**: This was my original answer before the Astra press release with the preliminary incident result. I will keep it here for hysterical raisins.

This is a recent incident under active investigation. On some other sites, this would make your question automatically off-topic until the official report is published. On this site, your question is on-topic, but it is still not definitively answerable since *even if* Astra had already completed its investigation, they would first share it with the FAA before the public.

The best you will get is some random people on the interwebs making uninformed guesses. However, guessing is fun, so this random person will make an uninformed guess.

[Scott Manley](https://twitter.com/DJSnM) did a thorough investigation:

of what little publicly accessible video

there is.

On Astra's Rocket 3, the second stage is fully enclosed in the payload fairing:

In a normal staging event:

the sequence of events is roughly the following:

1. First-stage engine cutoff
2. Payload fairing separation
3. Stage separation
4. Second-stage engine ignition

However, what happened with LV0008 was roughly the following:

1. First-stage engine cutoff
2. Payload fairings *did not separate*
3. The stages did separate, but since the payload fairings did not separate, the second stage just bumped against the payload fairing but stayed essentially on top of the first stage
4. The second stage engine ignites while the second stage is still inside the payload fairing
5. It looks like even the thrust of the engine is not enough to break the payload fairing apart, it is finally separated by the pressure of the rapidly expanding exhaust gases

From this point on, we are really getting into heavy speculation territory. Maybe the violent separation event damaged something on the second stage, like a sensor, a controller, or an actuator, which forced the second stage into a spin. Maybe, nothing was damaged, but the spin was somehow imparted onto the second stage and was too fast to recover from.

Comment: Scott's videos are fairly clear. We can see that the fairing latch in view of the camera did not operate correctly, as compared to a successful launch. There is also evidence that the fairing latch on the other side did operate, at least partially. So when the second stage engine ignited, there were highly asymmetric forces acting on the second stage, and this is what imparted the tumbling motion.